# Mysql group and sum based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to group and sum columns based on a condition?

```
id  |  code  |  total | to_update
1   |  A1001 |  2     | 0
2   |  B2001 |  1     | 1
3   |  A1001 |  5     | 1
4   |  A1001 |  3     | 0
5   |  A1001 |  2     | 0
6   |  B2001 |  1     | 0
7   |  C2001 |  11    | 0
8   |  C2001 |  20    | 0
```

In this example I want to group and sum all rows which share the same `code` where at least one row has an `to_update` value of 1.  Group by `code` column and sum by `total`.

The example above would result in:

```
code  total
A1001 12
B2001 2
```

Comment: The expected outcome sums those codes, where at least one of the records has update value of one, as opposed to how you described the task. So, which version is the correct one?

Comment: Yes where at least one record has an update value.  I will try to reword but that that was my intention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a subquery that gives you all codes that have at least 1 record where update=1 and you need to join this back to your table and do the group by and sum:

```
select m.code, sum(total)
from mytable m
inner join (select distinct code from mytable where `to_update`=1) t on m.code=t.code
group by m.code
```

Or you can sum the to_update column as well and filter in having:

```
select m.code, sum(total)
from mytable m
group by m.code   
having sum(to_update)> 0
```

Comment: We had the same thought on the `inner join` query.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT   code, SUM(total) AS total
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY code
HAVING   MAX(to_update) = 1
```

This assumes that the possible values of *to_update* are 0 or 1.

Implemented in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d81f/1), which outputs the result as requested in the question.

As this query only scans the table once, it will have better performance than solutions that make joins.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways that you can get the result. One way would be to get the `code` values that have an `to_update = 1`, then you can use this to get the `sum` of `total`.  This can be done a few different ways - one would be with a subquery that you join to:

```
select 
  t1.code,
  sum(total) as Total
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select distinct t.code
  from yourtable t
  where t.to_update = 1
) t2
  on t1.code = t2.code
group by t1.code;
```

Or you can use a `where exists` to filter out the rows:

```
select 
  t1.code,
  sum(total) as Total
from yourtable t1
where exists (select 1
              from yourtable t2
              where t2.to_update = 1
                and t1.code = t2.code)
group by t1.code;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f61071/1) of both versions.  Either way, you'll want to filter the rows based on the `to_update` value, then aggregate it.

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
SELECT
a.code,
a.total
FROM
(SELECT all
  code as code,
  sum(total) as total,
  sum(`sum`.`update`) as status
  FROM `Test`.`sum`
  GROUP BY code) as a
WHERE a.status <> 0;
```

You have:

```
A1001   12
B2001   2
```

It is sufficient that there is an update to have status different from 0.

Regards

Comment: This is a bit of an overkill, you do not need a subquery for this, just filter in having.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an in clause to select the list of codes that have a to_update=1 value and then use a group by clause to get the total

```
select code,sum(total) as total from sample 
where code in (select distinct code from sample where to_update=1) 
group by code
```